# Visual Basic 2013 - Form não consegue acessar/modificar dados de um Module

Tags: vb.net, visual-basic-6

Meu problema é o seguinte. Eu tenho este modulo que contêm uma variavel do tipo integer e essa variável é acessada por uma form que altera seu valor, como mostra o código abaixo.

```
Module Module1
       Public frm1 As New Form1
       Public frm2 As New Form2

       Public Uso As Integer
End Module

Public Class Form1
...
    Private Sub MenuItem4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MenuItem4.Click
        Uso = 1
        frm2 = New Form2
        frm2.MdiParent = Me
        frm2.Text = "PROJETO DE TROCADOR DE CALOR"
        frm2.Show()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Ao compilar ele abre normalmente a form1 (MdiContainer). Quando tento abrir um novo arquivo, `MenuItem4_Click`, gera uma exceção. Diz que a referência de um objeto não foi definida para uma instância deste objeto.

Este erro acontece com TODAS as variáveis deste Module1 que o frm2 tenta acessar/modificar.

Já fiz outros programas usando a mesma lógica que nunca deram este erro bizarro. Preciso mesmo de ajuda!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na linha

```
frm2 = New Form2
```

Você não declarou, apenas definiu a variável `frm2` para uma nova `Form2`, resolva isso com [Dim](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/7ee5a7s1.aspx). Seu código também está muito incompleto, coloque a declaração das variáveis (todas) que foram usadas nesse código para podermos ter uma noção melhor sobre o erro.

Comment: O que acontece é que quando eu preciso atribuir um valor à variável Uso ele cai em uma exceção e diz que a referência do objeto não foi definida para uma instância deste objeto. Não tem nada a ver com o frm2 que já foi anteriormente declarado!!!

Comment: Referência de um objeto não definida para instância de um objeto é sinônimo de objeto nulo, sem valor, olhe bem no seu código, usa a variável `New` e repare se não há nenhuma variável referenciada.

Comment: Consegui, Cypher! Deu certo! Tinha uma referência errada mesmo, no código do frm2 e que não deixava ele ser iniciado! Como é um programa feito no VB 2003 que foi convertido para o 2013 apareceram estes erros bizarros de referências inválidas!